# How to check login in index.html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I can check with **"index.php"**:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['id']))    { ?>
<li><a href="controller.php?type=logout" class="btn btn-borders btn-primary">Log out</a></li>
<?php }else{ ?>
<li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
<li><a href="login.html" class="btn btn-borders btn-primary">Log In</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to do the same on **"index.html"**. 
PHP won't read an HTML file; how can I check?

Comment: not possible with html page try javascript instead

Comment: yeah can you suggest javascript code

Comment: Why do you need index.html?  Just remove it and Apache will default to index.php automatically, or just have index.html auto transfer to index.php

Comment: I know @forbes but i want to use it in html page

Comment: this question seems like you want to solve a different problem than you're describing. If you want the url to appear like it's .html -> url rewrite. Depending on what else you want to do in the page, you're offloading work that might belong on the server side (and html and everything in it - including javascript - is usually client side first). You can't *trust* the user to execute javascript in the way you want them to.

Comment: How's your Jquery?  It can be done using Jquery to call a php program inside of the html, however that's way beyond something I can answer here

Comment: in javascript too u need php code to check session id and then assign it to javascript variable

Comment: No problem is not url rewritning.. I want to check session if logged in logout button has to apper and signup/login has to hide

Comment: yeah forbes answer jquery is fine

Comment: @AbdulWaheed, this site is not for people to write your code.  I suggest that you work on the JQuery code for this.  If it works, post and accept an answer; if not, post another question for help.

Comment: if you want to run an html file as php, you need to configure your server to do so (ex. by using .htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run PHP in .html files because the server does not recognize that as a valid PHP extension. You need to create a .htaccess file in your root web directory and add a line into it to tell the server to treat .html as a valid extension. Add this line to the newly created .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

This tells apache to treat .html extension as .php extension